# Кириллица в именах переменных

Tags: кириллица, переменные

Как известно, кириллица в именах переменых это плохо. А почему? Ну, кроме известного довода, что "а если вы будете работать с иностранными программистами?" 
P.S. Предположим, что речь идет о языке полностью поддерживающем Юникод.

Comment: Английский язык является общепринятым международным языком программирования (как латынь в древности), использование (грамотного!) английского для идентификаторов на сегодня по факту один из показателей профессионализма.

Comment: Условие  "а если вы будете работать с иностранными программистами?" можно и нужно изменить: "а если вы не будете использовать ни одной сторонней библиотеки?" В хоть сколько-нибудь серьёзных проектах уровнем выше "hello, world" это нереально. Да и там не получится :) Представьте, что вам "всего-то" нужен boost или STL. В результате получится такой трэш и угар, что сразу захочется выкинуть эту мысль из головы.

Comment: извините мою неопытность а чем опасно то что я в своем проекте с кириллицей буду использовать сторонние библиотеки? что тогда может случиться?

Comment: Будет смесь французского с нижегородским, в которой даже автор не сможет разобраться через несколько дней. Такой код годится разве что для [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) и ни для чего больше.

Comment: > Предположим что речь идет о языке полностью поддерживающем юникод

Как правильно заметили - как только встретится символ смены направления чтения, то случится ....

‏Сами смотрите.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Даже без иностранных программистов можно найти несколько относительно веских причин:

1. Русские слова обычно длиннее английских ("получить" - "get", "страница" - "page", ну и так далее). Это, конечно, не всегда так, но в целом - соблюдается
2. Необходимость постоянного переключения раскладки
3. Каша из русских и английских слов визуально плохо выглядит

Comment: да, русские слова обычно длинее, но в критических случаях средняя длина русских слов доходит до 3.5-4 букв на слово :) (если я правильно помню цифры, то в английском средняя длина - 5.5, в русском - 6.5, а в японском более десяти (в данном случае звуков)).

Хотя вот взял текст "Преступления и наказания", прогнал через линусковый wc, который показывает кол-во слов и символов. Получилось `2130519 символов/191521 слов = 11.1` Даже если вычесть 2 (на пробелы и пунктуацию), все равно много. Для английского я взял Отелло (Шекспир) = `150129/27732 = 5.4`...

Comment: это вы, конечно, молодец, что провели такую работу, но все же, наверное, язык со времен Достоевского сильно изменился...ну а тем более, со времен Шекспира)

Comment: а что, это большая работа? запустить wc в консоли? и потом разделить.

Comment: @KoVadim краткими выражения на русском становятся при использовании мата...

Answer (score 9):

Я лично вижу три проблемы:

- постоянно переключать раскладку клавиатуры. Программисты ленивые и каждый раз переключаться... А ещё какой-нибудь пунтосвитчер захочет исправлять имена переменных...
- появляются чудовозможности для генерации багов. Вот к примеру чем отличаются переменные `int a` и `int а`?  а это с точки зрения компилятора - разные переменные. (подсказка - одна а - кириллическая). Хотя на первый взгляд это кажется бредовым, мол, недопустят такого, но по факту это всегда может случиться. Но на самом то деле это как раз и является по моему мнению, главным аргументом, почему не приживаются "интернациональные имена переменных".
- ну и на закуску. Как представлю себе код, в котором имена переменных написаны китайским и арабским (не забываем, что в этом языке все записывается справа налево!).  А код откроют в каком то редакторе, который не полностью поддерживает юникод и часть текста отображается квадратиками. Плюс ко всему, редактирования арабской вязи - это ещё то удовольствие (настойчиво рекомендую попробовать!). Думаю, такой код будут быстро рефакторить и приводить к удобочитаемому.

Comment: @KoVadim зато как красиво смотрятся имена типа EtoNovajPeremennaj

Comment: [фтемупрям!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11462/7313)  
не понимал в чём прикол, пока не запустил в браузере

Answer (score 2):

Кириллица - это в высшей степени патриотично.
Но многие заказчики тешат себя надеждой, что код, который вы для них написали, они потом смогут продать за бугор.  Или что его фирма вырастет до международных масштабов, и программисты других стран (индусы?) будут поддерживать ваш код.  Так сказать, Новые Васюки станут центром вселенной.  Вот поэтому нам и не дают писать расово-правильный код. ))

Comment: ну это конечно да но я все же имел в виду, что "если с данным кодом не будет работать иностранные программисты")

Comment: @JuniorTwo - если вы пишете для себя, а не по заказу <s>гостелерадио</s>, то пишите как хотите.

Answer (score 0):

Нет в ней ничего плохого за исключением необходимости переключать раскладку. Ну и однобуквенные переменные не надо кириллицей называть. Раньше писал так. Вот если бы нормальный свитчер был, то и сейчас бы продолжал, наверное.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но это уже было (по рассказам, местами встречалось еще лет 40 назад, например, КОБОЛ даже с ключевыми словами на русском...) Было то было, но поскольку массой программеров воспринималось как явное уродство + засилье сдироскопии, то ушло. Я сам однажды (в конце 80-х попросили ошибочки помочь найти, подробностей уже не помню) видел ассемблер с русскими мнемониками для какого-то  стекового вычислителя -- представьте `CЛЖ / ПЕРБЧ МЕТ11 / ...` Наверное, если привыкнуть, то сгодится, а сходу глаза режет и просто ничего в голову не лезет.